# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE will not work with ip address

Tags: mysql, windows, insert, unc

I want to use the mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with an environment that has sql on one server and the files on another server.

The server with the files on it has an ip address of: 192.XXX.XX.XX

The path to the file on the file server is: C:/repos/example.com/web/matches/temp/

My mysql that I have right now, which is not working is below:

```
LOAD DATA 
           LOCAL INFILE '//192.XXX.XX.XX/C:/repos/example.com/web/matches/temp/20180218test08Y_PeopleInMatches.txt' 
            INTO TABLE EventResultsSwimmersInSwims 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (UserID, CompetitorID, UserNumber, Time) 
        SET 
            MatchID = "20180218test08Y";
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

'LOCAL' should be interpreted literally. It means the system on which the mysql client is running. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
>   client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
>   path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path
>   name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the
>   client program was started.

The alternative, i.e. without 'LOCAL' is for the file to read from a directory on the database server itself.

Comment: The file is on not on the db server but on the web server that has the webpages. So remove the 'LOCAL'?

Comment: Install a mysql client on the webserver (assuming you don't have one there already) and use a local path to the file. Or, copy the file to the server (preferably into the directory pointed to by the secure_file_priv variable and load it from there without the LOCAL keyword.